# Facebook automatic page posting posts to all my pages (raspbian)

Tags: linux, facebook, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I own a couple of facebook pages. A friend and I have developed an app that can run on the raspbian and that can post on facebook when we want it to. It uploads pictures from a specific map to facebook. The script is in .sh.

To accomplish this I needed a page token and a facebook app. The facebook app is needed to direct the messages towards the page. The page token I got from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ (select the app needed, then select which page token I want to generate and make it into a permanent token).

I then use cronjobs to automate this process and upload the images when I want to upload. For example:

15 * * * * /home/pi/Directory1/Script1

50 * * * * /home/pi/Directory2/Script2

30 * * * * /home/pi/Directory3/Script3

43 * * * * /home/pi/Directory4/Script4

My problem is that when I use cronjobs the page posting interferes. Images on page 1 get also posted on page 2 and the other way around. I have no clue how to fix this as I have tried nearly anything. When running the script on its own without cronjobs it seems to work perfectly but automated it does not.

If you have any suggestion that I can try please tell me so. Thank you!

Comment: You already posted about this before. The problem is that you are using the wrong access token.

Comment: And I replied why that was not the case

Comment: So why are you making a new post?